# Go to definition for local python packages in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to switch from PyCharm to VS Code to write python code. But I've problems with navigation (specially `Go to definition`) through my code.

My project structure is something like this:

```
- my_pkg
    setup.py
    README.md
    - my_pkg
        - celery
            tasks.py
        - foo 
            main.py
```

in `my_pkg/my_pkg/celery/tasks.py` I need `func_bar` from `my_pkg/my_pkg/foo/main.py`. So I import it like this:

`from my_pkg.foo.main import func_bar`

`Go to definition` works fine in PyCharm. 
I also install `my_pkg` locally like this: `cd ~/my_pkg; pip install -e .`

But in VSCode I cannot go to the definition if I use this ^^ import, instead I have to do it in one of these ways:

`from my_pkg.my_pkg.foo.main import func_bar`

or

`from ..my_pkg.foo.main import func_bar`

*Problem*: In these case, `Go to definition` works, but my code does not work anymore.

For example in ipython:

`from my_pkg.my_pkg.foo.main import func_bar`
raises `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_pkg.mypkg'`

I'm using VS Code `Version 1.26.1 (1.26.1)` on macOS with python 3.6.4.

My workspace settings:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "${workspaceRoot}/virtual/bin/python",
    "python.venvPath": "${workspaceRoot}/virtual",
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages"
    ],
    "python.unitTest.pyTestEnabled": true
}
```

And it works fine for external installed packages via pip.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

I've had `__init__.py` in both root `my_pkg` and also in `my_pkg/my_pkg` directory. So VS Code choose the root `my_pkg` as the referent.

So to resolve this, I just needed to delete `my_pkg/__init__.py`.